# Missing values in economic time series

Tags: econometrics, time-series

I am trying to run a time series analysis on some variables - GDP being my dependent variable, and my independent variables are oil revenues, government expenditure, exports and FDI inflows. My data contains missing values for some years for at least 3 variables. I have been able to ascertain that they are non-stationary. However, I am unable to perform the Johansen test of cointegration due to the missing variables in between the data set. How do I resolve this?

Comment: I don't know if software questions are on topic here. This was discussed in a meta question: http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/78/are-software-questions-on-topic
Nevertheless, it seems to me that a question about how to treat missing values is not *economics* per se, so I would advice you check the Stata help documentation, ask on stats.SE or on Statalist.

Comment: Stata's multiple imputation function (mi) might be a good place to start.

Comment: @Majoko I think they would be better suited else where, but are still on-topic here. But let's move that discussion to meta.

Answer (score 3):

The paper [Cointegrating Regressions with Messy Regressors: Missingness, Mixed Frequency, and Measurement Error](http://hdl.handle.net/10355/2541) (J. Isaac Miller (2009)) seems to have what you are looking for.

> We consider a cointegrating regression in which the integrated
>   regressors are messy in the sense that they contain data that may be
>   mismeasured, missing, observed at mixed frequencies, or have other
>   irregularities that cause the econo- metrician to observe them with
>   mildly nonstationary noise. Least squares esti- mation of the
>   cointegrating vector is consistent. Existing prototypical variance-
>   based estimation techniques, such as canonical cointegrating
>   regression (CCR), are both consistent and asymptotically mixed normal.
>   This result is robust to weakly dependent but possibly nonstationary
>   disturbances.

Here  is the bit on testing for cointegration:

> In cases where cointegration between ($y_ t$) and ($x_t$) is not
>   obvious or expected, 5 testing is desirable. The variance ratio test
>   and multivariate trace statistic proposed by Phillips and Ouliaris
>   (1990) rely on the estimation of the long-run variance of a different
>   residual series. Specifically, ($y_ t, x'_t$ ) is regressed on one lag
>   of itself, and the long-run variance of the residual series from that
>   regression is estimated. This series is I(0) under the null, so we can
>   expect that adding ($z^*_t$) – i.e., using ($y_ t, x^{'*}_t$)  – would
>   have a similar effect to adding ($z^*_t$) to the residual series
>   below. Specifically, it would inflate the variance of both the
>   numerator and denominator of these statistics, so that the limits
>   would be preserved. Approaches using more robust variance ratio tests
>   (Wright, 2000; Müller and Watson, 2008) hold more promise still.